# ViewPager first page not updating

Tags: android-viewpager

ViewPager first page and second page duplicates, but when I have more than 4 pages on scrolling first page and second page displayed with correct value.![enter image description here

Answer (score 0):

Send page parameters via bundle args:

```
public static mFragment create(int param) {
    mFragment fragment = new mFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("paramname", param);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

then read:

```
mParam = getArguments().getInt("paramname");
```